# What is the REAL password for Bond's account?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

In *Casino Royale*, James Bond is required to enter a password into a security device. Later in the film, he reveals that the password *he supposedly* entered was Vesper...

However, the brief shot we of him entering the code shows him using the number 4, making it impossible that the code be Vesper, as [this website](http://www.moviemistakes.com/film6299) points out:

> When Bond enters his password in the casino, he enters 836547. He
>   later gives the password as VESPER, which on an alpha-numeric keypad
>   would be 837737.

If we are to take it that this is a goof (which it almost certainly is), it stands to reason that at the time of filming *a different* password was considered: it's unlikely whomever is responsible for the close-up shot of him entering the code was illiterate enough to enter the wrong code, and even more so for the continuity department not to notice (although, they clearly missed this from the final cut: so it's not entirely implausible).

Could it be possible that another password was originally intended to be used; one that required the keys 836547 in spelling it? can anyone figure out what this original password could have been, before it was (possibly) re-conned to be Vesper?

---

### To reiterate for clarity, considering answers supplied:

We KNOW this is, in some way or another, *a mistake*. **Continuity goof** is not the answer we are looking for, we're trying to work out what the original password the actor was told he was typing into the keypad was. It's an unlikely (and thus rejected) hypothesis that for such a key close up in the movie, the actor was told to just type a random code in. There must be some contextual purpose that was perhaps later changed.

We know the word corresponds to the keypad letters **836547** as we see him type it in. What could this word have been?

Comment: While this is an interesting possibility I'd doubt it was anything else but because noone cared enough what numbers he enters at all, thinking that noone (apart from some "goof-hunters") would actually notice it anyway. But I would have to recheck the scene to see how ovious it was at all what he entered.

Comment: I might be dead wrong but from a brief look, the combination 836547 doesn't seem to spell any word in English.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the actual scene, it's really a very obvious close-up. My proposed *"don't care"*-attitude from the filmmakers' side might not apply too much then.

Comment: @Walt - Vesper is a name, it's not English. Using one of the many number to word calculators on the web, even the Vesper correct code doesn't come up with any names.

Comment: BTW, in the end Vesper enters a password that correctly ends in 737. So IMO that previous scene was probably just a goof-up, however blatant. See here at 1:01: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIELUql42kA

Comment: "Hi, question for Ms. Bellamy. In episode 2F09, when Itchy plays Scratchy's skeleton like a xylophone, he strikes that same rib twice in succession yet he produces two clearly different tones. I mean, what are we, to believe that this is some sort of a, a magic xylophone or something? Boy, I really hope somebody got fired for that blunder." - The Simpsons, Season 8, Episode 14: "The Itchy & Scratchy & Poochie Show"

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the keypad in the film:

[image]

we see that `836547` could correspond to any of the following 972 (= 3<sup>5</sup> * 4) string combinations:

```
tdmjgp, tdmjgq, tdmjgr, tdmjgs, tdmjhp, tdmjhq, tdmjhr, tdmjhs, tdmjip, tdmjiq, tdmjir, tdmjis, tdmkgp, tdmkgq, tdmkgr, tdmkgs, tdmkhp, tdmkhq, tdmkhr, tdmkhs, tdmkip, tdmkiq, tdmkir, tdmkis, tdmlgp, tdmlgq, tdmlgr, tdmlgs, tdmlhp, tdmlhq, tdmlhr, tdmlhs, tdmlip, tdmliq, tdmlir, tdmlis, tdnjgp, tdnjgq, tdnjgr, tdnjgs, tdnjhp, tdnjhq, tdnjhr, tdnjhs, tdnjip, tdnjiq, tdnjir, tdnjis, tdnkgp, tdnkgq, tdnkgr, tdnkgs, tdnkhp, tdnkhq, tdnkhr, tdnkhs, tdnkip, tdnkiq, tdnkir, tdnkis, tdnlgp, tdnlgq, tdnlgr, tdnlgs, tdnlhp, tdnlhq, tdnlhr, tdnlhs, tdnlip, tdnliq, tdnlir, tdnlis, tdojgp, tdojgq, tdojgr, tdojgs, tdojhp, tdojhq, tdojhr, tdojhs, tdojip, tdojiq, tdojir, tdojis, tdokgp, tdokgq, tdokgr, tdokgs, tdokhp, tdokhq, tdokhr, tdokhs, tdokip, tdokiq, tdokir, tdokis, tdolgp, tdolgq, tdolgr, tdolgs, tdolhp, tdolhq, tdolhr, tdolhs, tdolip, tdoliq, tdolir, tdolis, temjgp, temjgq, temjgr, temjgs, temjhp, temjhq, temjhr, temjhs, temjip, temjiq, temjir, temjis, temkgp, temkgq, temkgr, temkgs, temkhp, temkhq, temkhr, temkhs, temkip, temkiq, temkir, temkis, temlgp, temlgq, temlgr, temlgs, temlhp, temlhq, temlhr, temlhs, temlip, temliq, temlir, temlis, tenjgp, tenjgq, tenjgr, tenjgs, tenjhp, tenjhq, tenjhr, tenjhs, tenjip, tenjiq, tenjir, tenjis, tenkgp, tenkgq, tenkgr, tenkgs, tenkhp, tenkhq, tenkhr, tenkhs, tenkip, tenkiq, tenkir, tenkis, tenlgp, tenlgq, tenlgr, tenlgs, tenlhp, tenlhq, tenlhr, tenlhs, tenlip, tenliq, tenlir, tenlis, teojgp, teojgq, teojgr, teojgs, teojhp, teojhq, teojhr, teojhs, teojip, teojiq, teojir, teojis, teokgp, teokgq, teokgr, teokgs, teokhp, teokhq, teokhr, teokhs, teokip, teokiq, teokir, teokis, teolgp, teolgq, teolgr, teolgs, teolhp, teolhq, teolhr, teolhs, teolip, teoliq, teolir, teolis, tfmjgp, tfmjgq, tfmjgr, tfmjgs, tfmjhp, tfmjhq, tfmjhr, tfmjhs, tfmjip, tfmjiq, tfmjir, tfmjis, tfmkgp, tfmkgq, tfmkgr, tfmkgs, tfmkhp, tfmkhq, tfmkhr, tfmkhs, tfmkip, tfmkiq, tfmkir, tfmkis, tfmlgp, tfmlgq, tfmlgr, tfmlgs, tfmlhp, tfmlhq, tfmlhr, tfmlhs, tfmlip, tfmliq, tfmlir, tfmlis, tfnjgp, tfnjgq, tfnjgr, tfnjgs, tfnjhp, tfnjhq, tfnjhr, tfnjhs, tfnjip, tfnjiq, tfnjir, tfnjis, tfnkgp, tfnkgq, tfnkgr, tfnkgs, tfnkhp, tfnkhq, tfnkhr, tfnkhs, tfnkip, tfnkiq, tfnkir, tfnkis, tfnlgp, tfnlgq, tfnlgr, tfnlgs, tfnlhp, tfnlhq, tfnlhr, tfnlhs, tfnlip, tfnliq, tfnlir, tfnlis, tfojgp, tfojgq, tfojgr, tfojgs, tfojhp, tfojhq, tfojhr, tfojhs, tfojip, tfojiq, tfojir, tfojis, tfokgp, tfokgq, tfokgr, tfokgs, tfokhp, tfokhq, tfokhr, tfokhs, tfokip, tfokiq, tfokir, tfokis, tfolgp, tfolgq, tfolgr, tfolgs, tfolhp, tfolhq, tfolhr, tfolhs, tfolip, tfoliq, tfolir, tfolis, udmjgp, udmjgq, udmjgr, udmjgs, udmjhp, udmjhq, udmjhr, udmjhs, udmjip, udmjiq, udmjir, udmjis, udmkgp, udmkgq, udmkgr, udmkgs, udmkhp, udmkhq, udmkhr, udmkhs, udmkip, udmkiq, udmkir, udmkis, udmlgp, udmlgq, udmlgr, udmlgs, udmlhp, udmlhq, udmlhr, udmlhs, udmlip, udmliq, udmlir, udmlis, udnjgp, udnjgq, udnjgr, udnjgs, udnjhp, udnjhq, udnjhr, udnjhs, udnjip, udnjiq, udnjir, udnjis, udnkgp, udnkgq, udnkgr, udnkgs, udnkhp, udnkhq, udnkhr, udnkhs, udnkip, udnkiq, udnkir, udnkis, udnlgp, udnlgq, udnlgr, udnlgs, udnlhp, udnlhq, udnlhr, udnlhs, udnlip, udnliq, udnlir, udnlis, udojgp, udojgq, udojgr, udojgs, udojhp, udojhq, udojhr, udojhs, udojip, udojiq, udojir, udojis, udokgp, udokgq, udokgr, udokgs, udokhp, udokhq, udokhr, udokhs, udokip, udokiq, udokir, udokis, udolgp, udolgq, udolgr, udolgs, udolhp, udolhq, udolhr, udolhs, udolip, udoliq, udolir, udolis, uemjgp, uemjgq, uemjgr, uemjgs, uemjhp, uemjhq, uemjhr, uemjhs, uemjip, uemjiq, uemjir, uemjis, uemkgp, uemkgq, uemkgr, uemkgs, uemkhp, uemkhq, uemkhr, uemkhs, uemkip, uemkiq, uemkir, uemkis, uemlgp, uemlgq, uemlgr, uemlgs, uemlhp, uemlhq, uemlhr, uemlhs, uemlip, uemliq, uemlir, uemlis, uenjgp, uenjgq, uenjgr, uenjgs, uenjhp, uenjhq, uenjhr, uenjhs, uenjip, uenjiq, uenjir, uenjis, uenkgp, uenkgq, uenkgr, uenkgs, uenkhp, uenkhq, uenkhr, uenkhs, uenkip, uenkiq, uenkir, uenkis, uenlgp, uenlgq, uenlgr, uenlgs, uenlhp, uenlhq, uenlhr, uenlhs, uenlip, uenliq, uenlir, uenlis, ueojgp, ueojgq, ueojgr, ueojgs, ueojhp, ueojhq, ueojhr, ueojhs, ueojip, ueojiq, ueojir, ueojis, ueokgp, ueokgq, ueokgr, ueokgs, ueokhp, ueokhq, ueokhr, ueokhs, ueokip, ueokiq, ueokir, ueokis, ueolgp, ueolgq, ueolgr, ueolgs, ueolhp, ueolhq, ueolhr, ueolhs, ueolip, ueoliq, ueolir, ueolis, ufmjgp, ufmjgq, ufmjgr, ufmjgs, ufmjhp, ufmjhq, ufmjhr, ufmjhs, ufmjip, ufmjiq, ufmjir, ufmjis, ufmkgp, ufmkgq, ufmkgr, ufmkgs, ufmkhp, ufmkhq, ufmkhr, ufmkhs, ufmkip, ufmkiq, ufmkir, ufmkis, ufmlgp, ufmlgq, ufmlgr, ufmlgs, ufmlhp, ufmlhq, ufmlhr, ufmlhs, ufmlip, ufmliq, ufmlir, ufmlis, ufnjgp, ufnjgq, ufnjgr, ufnjgs, ufnjhp, ufnjhq, ufnjhr, ufnjhs, ufnjip, ufnjiq, ufnjir, ufnjis, ufnkgp, ufnkgq, ufnkgr, ufnkgs, ufnkhp, ufnkhq, ufnkhr, ufnkhs, ufnkip, ufnkiq, ufnkir, ufnkis, ufnlgp, ufnlgq, ufnlgr, ufnlgs, ufnlhp, ufnlhq, ufnlhr, ufnlhs, ufnlip, ufnliq, ufnlir, ufnlis, ufojgp, ufojgq, ufojgr, ufojgs, ufojhp, ufojhq, ufojhr, ufojhs, ufojip, ufojiq, ufojir, ufojis, ufokgp, ufokgq, ufokgr, ufokgs, ufokhp, ufokhq, ufokhr, ufokhs, ufokip, ufokiq, ufokir, ufokis, ufolgp, ufolgq, ufolgr, ufolgs, ufolhp, ufolhq, ufolhr, ufolhs, ufolip, ufoliq, ufolir, ufolis, vdmjgp, vdmjgq, vdmjgr, vdmjgs, vdmjhp, vdmjhq, vdmjhr, vdmjhs, vdmjip, vdmjiq, vdmjir, vdmjis, vdmkgp, vdmkgq, vdmkgr, vdmkgs, vdmkhp, vdmkhq, vdmkhr, vdmkhs, vdmkip, vdmkiq, vdmkir, vdmkis, vdmlgp, vdmlgq, vdmlgr, vdmlgs, vdmlhp, vdmlhq, vdmlhr, vdmlhs, vdmlip, vdmliq, vdmlir, vdmlis, vdnjgp, vdnjgq, vdnjgr, vdnjgs, vdnjhp, vdnjhq, vdnjhr, vdnjhs, vdnjip, vdnjiq, vdnjir, vdnjis, vdnkgp, vdnkgq, vdnkgr, vdnkgs, vdnkhp, vdnkhq, vdnkhr, vdnkhs, vdnkip, vdnkiq, vdnkir, vdnkis, vdnlgp, vdnlgq, vdnlgr, vdnlgs, vdnlhp, vdnlhq, vdnlhr, vdnlhs, vdnlip, vdnliq, vdnlir, vdnlis, vdojgp, vdojgq, vdojgr, vdojgs, vdojhp, vdojhq, vdojhr, vdojhs, vdojip, vdojiq, vdojir, vdojis, vdokgp, vdokgq, vdokgr, vdokgs, vdokhp, vdokhq, vdokhr, vdokhs, vdokip, vdokiq, vdokir, vdokis, vdolgp, vdolgq, vdolgr, vdolgs, vdolhp, vdolhq, vdolhr, vdolhs, vdolip, vdoliq, vdolir, vdolis, vemjgp, vemjgq, vemjgr, vemjgs, vemjhp, vemjhq, vemjhr, vemjhs, vemjip, vemjiq, vemjir, vemjis, vemkgp, vemkgq, vemkgr, vemkgs, vemkhp, vemkhq, vemkhr, vemkhs, vemkip, vemkiq, vemkir, vemkis, vemlgp, vemlgq, vemlgr, vemlgs, vemlhp, vemlhq, vemlhr, vemlhs, vemlip, vemliq, vemlir, vemlis, venjgp, venjgq, venjgr, venjgs, venjhp, venjhq, venjhr, venjhs, venjip, venjiq, venjir, venjis, venkgp, venkgq, venkgr, venkgs, venkhp, venkhq, venkhr, venkhs, venkip, venkiq, venkir, venkis, venlgp, venlgq, venlgr, venlgs, venlhp, venlhq, venlhr, venlhs, venlip, venliq, venlir, venlis, veojgp, veojgq, veojgr, veojgs, veojhp, veojhq, veojhr, veojhs, veojip, veojiq, veojir, veojis, veokgp, veokgq, veokgr, veokgs, veokhp, veokhq, veokhr, veokhs, veokip, veokiq, veokir, veokis, veolgp, veolgq, veolgr, veolgs, veolhp, veolhq, veolhr, veolhs, veolip, veoliq, veolir, veolis, vfmjgp, vfmjgq, vfmjgr, vfmjgs, vfmjhp, vfmjhq, vfmjhr, vfmjhs, vfmjip, vfmjiq, vfmjir, vfmjis, vfmkgp, vfmkgq, vfmkgr, vfmkgs, vfmkhp, vfmkhq, vfmkhr, vfmkhs, vfmkip, vfmkiq, vfmkir, vfmkis, vfmlgp, vfmlgq, vfmlgr, vfmlgs, vfmlhp, vfmlhq, vfmlhr, vfmlhs, vfmlip, vfmliq, vfmlir, vfmlis, vfnjgp, vfnjgq, vfnjgr, vfnjgs, vfnjhp, vfnjhq, vfnjhr, vfnjhs, vfnjip, vfnjiq, vfnjir, vfnjis, vfnkgp, vfnkgq, vfnkgr, vfnkgs, vfnkhp, vfnkhq, vfnkhr, vfnkhs, vfnkip, vfnkiq, vfnkir, vfnkis, vfnlgp, vfnlgq, vfnlgr, vfnlgs, vfnlhp, vfnlhq, vfnlhr, vfnlhs, vfnlip, vfnliq, vfnlir, vfnlis, vfojgp, vfojgq, vfojgr, vfojgs, vfojhp, vfojhq, vfojhr, vfojhs, vfojip, vfojiq, vfojir, vfojis, vfokgp, vfokgq, vfokgr, vfokgs, vfokhp, vfokhq, vfokhr, vfokhs, vfokip, vfokiq, vfokir, vfokis, vfolgp, vfolgq, vfolgr, vfolgs, vfolhp, vfolhq, vfolhr, vfolhs, vfolip, vfoliq, vfolir, vfolis
```

None of these, however, are English words. But, if we consider it as a concatenation of two words, we are left with this possible set:

`temkip, temlip, temliq, tenkip, tenlip, tenliq, ufokip, ufolip, ufoliq`

i.e. combinations of *[TEM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/TEM), ten, UFO* and *kip, lip, [liq.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/liq-)*.

It could also be an acronym (possibly one ending in `HQ`).

Comment: `venkis` is apparently a form of a verb relating to victory in Esperanto. `Kiu venkis?` = `Who won?` https://www.duolingo.com/dictionary/Esperanto/venkis/fbfcfb3cb4c671fee9e3d2128ffb92ed

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a non-answer, but having watched the scene(s) many times and scoured the Internet, I'm going to say it's just a **movie mistake**. It's certainly identified as such (continuity error) on most Movie Mistake websites.

My only reasoning is thus: one, there doesn't *appear* to be another solution and one is unlikely forthcoming and; two, despite the close up of the shot, it's certainly understandable that the editing team could have missed this. When you consider some continuity errors in films involve things appearing in one shot, missing in the next and then reappearing in the following shot, it certainly seems logical that the team could have just missed this.

I'll of course update this answer in future if more information is forthcoming, but for now I call movie mistake.

**Edit:**

The more I think about it, the more I have a slightly different conclusion. I think it's possible that the original pass code was just a random number that Bond was using, but later on, to demonstrate how much he cared about Vesper, it was shown he had changed his pass code to her name.

In my eyes, this act, something many people in relationships have done, enhances the feeling of betrayal he felt once he learnt her part in Schiffe's plan. She wasn't just a random woman he had bedded, but someone he had given his heart to.

Comment: A script supervisor and continuity editor are hired to make sure the frames don't contradict: that isn't what's happened here. Craig (or whichever stunt hand was responsible) was told to put a specific number in (836547), surely. It can't be continuity, as this would mean Craig (or stunt-hand) can't input a simple six digit code without getting the numbers wildly wrong... talk about fat fingers, he'd have to be doing it blindfolded...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Why can't they have just used different numbers and not realised? Far worse continuity errors have occurred in films.

Comment: ...because unless he was doing it blindfolded, he had to be putting *something* in... are you suggesting it was totally random? that on set they just said "we're gonna do a close up, type whatever you want."... even that wouldn't be a goof, he'd still have been told to type something, at least..

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Why not? Why not a totally random number? Or some convincing number that simply had to be a password that later on they decided to change and make it into "VESPER". I think given your background you know a lot more about this stuff than me, but my continuing defence is that I've seen some atrocious continuity errors in big budget Hollywood films, so the idea of this happening doesn't surprise me in the slightest.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but maybe you've not understood me: we know its a mistake, of course: it doesn't make sense, how could it not be a mistake? your "later on they decided to change" is actually written into the question as a possibility... what we're trying to figure out is what, if anything, that original password **WAS**, and its relevance (numerically or alphabetically) to Bond. it's not enough to say "Mistake", we know this already: the question was never 'is it a mistake?', it was could the password originally have been something else, and if so what?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Fair enough. In that case I guess my answer is "I see nothing it could have been and think it's most logical to assume it's a continuity error". I'll keep digging and see if I come up with anything more informative.

Answer (score 1):

Years later... Has anyone considered the Latin translation of ellipsis? Evening. It’s  a stretch but it does work. Ellipsis and evening begin with the same later. Eliminate the first letter in both  (as it’s the same— and it happens to work out) continue after the duplicate after ellipses and we get the code bond punched in, obviously in a respective order. 836-537 (VEN- eVENing, LIP-elLIPses). It’s a large stretch, but what’re the odds they truly didn’t look at the code he entered? Plausible on both sides, but I’m leaning on the side with closure.

Answer (score 0):

836547 [can spell out](http://phonespell.org/combo.cgi?n=836547) "**ten lip**."
"Ten" might be a reference to a "perfect ten" and "lip" might be a body part or the attitude/sass that body part can be used to express.

*It's much more likely this was a filming goof, but if you want something more interesting to think about in line with the story, there you go!*

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no mention in the script I found on the interweb.

[image: script]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm totally wrong but I can't help but to believe each time Bond entered a password it was for a different reason. At Montenegro the money was already in an account and the password was needed so they could transfer money in and out of each players account. My best is Vesper provided him with a password since she was "the money" hence Bond's password 836547. After Bond won the game all of the money from the other players accounts was transferred to his account. The money in the account at Montenegro stayed there until Mendel went to the hospital to see Bond. Mendel then requested the account number and password from Bond. But this time it was for a different account. Mendel needed the account number and password of the Bank account Bond wanted the money deposited into from the Montenegro account. Vesper knew the account number so she input the account numbers but she didn't know the password until she asked Bond and he replied was 837737 (Vesper).

Comment: Hi Lynd, I don't really follow your logic here, can you clarify? What do you mean by "a different reason", how does that influence the password itself? "My best is Vesper provided him..." - your best what? How does her being "the money" make that password 836547?

Comment: The first password Bond entered was for the casino to access his account with the $10 million dollars in it. That was so the Casino could withdraw or deposit money in and out of it based on his winnings or losses.

Comment: The second time a password was required Vesper had to enter the account number 1st. She didn't need to enter the account number of the account at the Casino in Montenegro as Mendel already had that account number. The account number she entered was for the Bank Account. Mendel needed that number so he could transfer the money from the Montenegro account into the bank account. The password Bond verbally gave Vesper was for the bank account the money was going to be deposited into. If the movie had shown the bank account in Italy being set up the whole sequence would have made sense.

Comment: The first code was 836547. This is the code that has challenged everyone. Could it be... M's real name is Olivia. Olivia is 654842. We know Vesper is 837737. Combine the two 8=V 3=E 6=O 5=L 4=I 7=S. At the time the first code was entered Vesper and M (Olivia) were both in his life. So this code contained letters from both women's names. Changing the code to 837737 from 836547 represented he was willing to leave M and his position as a Spy behind for Vesper.

Answer (score -1):

It was supposed to be Vesper. But wouldn't translate to the movie if they used the correct corresponding numbers. Because he'd have to type the seven a few times. So I say they used the first two and last one letter.I doubt anyone will see my answer as this discussion is very old. But I had to give my two cents.

Answer (score -3):

I just found a website that admits all the mistakes made while filming Casino Royale, and by the looks of it the list of mistakes is pretty long.

> http://www.mi6-hq.com/sections/movies/cr_mistakes.php3?t=mi6&s=cr

To answer your question, I'll bring up the confession that admits the goof-up with the numbers.

> When Bond enters his pass code at the poker game, he enters 836547.
>   This combination of numbers cannot spell VESPER. However, at the end
>   of the film when Vesper Lynd enters the pass code, the last three
>   digits entered are 737 (which, indeed, can spell PER).

Comment: A website that **"admits"** sounds like it's official information from the film-makers. Is this in any way secured or could this just be a fan-site that simply "calls this out" as a mistake either?

Answer (score -3):

I think that 836547  has to be divided this way
83 - 65 - 47
Those are Vesper's body measures.
In the scene before we see Vesper giving Bond a perfect tailored smoking, hand made just for him. 
That's the point.
The password was just his "revenge" on her deduction skill about his own body.
The password is not Vesper but is anyway about her, or what Bond thought that her measurements are.
It has sense in that moment, it is connected with the scene before, the problem is in the end of the movie when he tells her that the password is her name... they should have paid more attention in that moment...

Comment: This is poor speculation. 83-65-47 (assuming centimeters) would be a very odd body shape. The actress who plays Vesper, Eva Green, [has measurements around](http://healthyceleb.com/eva-green-height-weight-body-statistics/27765) 89-61-89 cm.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe: It's even odder if you assume it's in inches...

Comment: I agree. It can't be Vesper's body measurements. btw, what exactly did Bond have against the "tailored" suit? When he says "It's tailored", why is he annoyed? Are ready-made suits better? I thought having a suit tailored to one's body contour is best.

Comment: @nav Regarding 'why is he annoyed' - I thought it was more surprise, as in - 'How could this be tailored since you haven't measured me? You must have amazing eyesight!'

Answer (score -4):

The number 836547 also spells venkis which in Esperanto comes from venki which means defeat. http://www.esperanto-panorama.net/vortaro/eoen.htm. James Bond knew he was going to defeat Le Chiffre and had a cleaver way of entering the word in another language.

Comment: I feel like this is a bit of a stretch. You'll need to elaborate more, and your link doesn't really provide anything to back up your answer.